# dispose is not a member of GDI+ Image class

Tags: c++, image, gdi+, dispose

So I have a program that pulls random images from a folder and creates a collage out of them, and set it to the windows wallpaper.  Which seems to work fine.  So I thought I would put in a sleep timer and let it automatically update itself without me having to run it every half hour or what ever.  I did that and it works great, but I ran into a problem of a memory leak that wasn't noticed before I started looping it.  I am attempting to dispose of the GDI+objects, but I keep getting the error that dispose is not a member of GDIplus::Image

I am loading an picture into an Image object, then resizing it and putting it into an array of Images, then I would like to dispose of the first Image.  I would then like to dispose of the array after I finish working with the images in it.

This is being done with an old copy of VS2005.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <objidl.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include "cwp05rnd.h"

using namespace Gdiplus;
using namespace std;
#pragma comment (lib,"Gdiplus.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "user32.lib")

int main()
{
GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
ULONG_PTR           gdiplusToken;
HDC                 hdc;
Graphics            graphics(hdc);

GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
CLSID jpegClsid;
GetEncoderClsid(L"image/jpeg", &jpegClsid);

SetCurrentDirectoryA("E:\\Photos");
ofstream outfile;
outfile.open ("outimgs.txt");
ofstream outfile2;
outfile2.open("imgpos.txt");

srand(time(NULL));
init_genrand(time(NULL));

vector<string>  dirlist;
DIR             *d;
struct          dirent *dir;

int i=0;
d=opendir(".");
if (d)
{
    while ((dir=readdir(d)) != NULL)
    {
        i++;
        dirlist.push_back(dir->d_name);
    }
    closedir(d);
}
Image   wp(L"E:\\Dropbox\\Photos\\wallpaper.jpg");
Graphics* wpimage = Graphics::FromImage(&wp);
int r;
int rvsize=100;
int rv[100]={0};
string img;
std::wstring wimg;
const wchar_t* rimg;
double cwidth;
double cheight;
double ratio;
int nheight;
int counter=0;
    int full = 0;
    int tries = 0;
    int hfull = 0;
    int imgnum =0;
    int last=0;
    Image* newpic[10];

    while ( tries <10)
    {
        redo:
        tries++;
        int newrv=0;
        while (newrv ==0)
        {

            r=genrand_int32()%i;
            for (int k=0; k < rvsize; k++)
            {

                if (rv[k] > 0 && rv[k]==r )
                {
                    break;
                }
                if (rv[k]==0 && r < i)
                {
                    newrv =1;
                    rv[k]=r;
                    last=k;
                    break;
                }
                if (rv[k] ==0)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
        img = dirlist[r];
        if (img[0]=='.')
        {
            newrv=0;
            goto redo;
        }
        wimg = std::wstring(img.begin(),img.end());

        rimg = wimg.c_str();

        Image pic(rimg);

        cwidth = pic.GetWidth();
        cheight = pic.GetHeight();
        if (cheight ==0)
        {
            outfile2 << "error" << img << endl;
            rv[last]=0;
            system("pause");
            goto redo;
        }
        ratio = cwidth/cheight;
        nheight = nwidth/ratio;
        pic.RotateFlip(Rotate180FlipNone);
        pic.RotateFlip(Rotate180FlipNone);
        newpic[imgnum] = pic.GetThumbnailImage(nwidth,nheight,NULL,NULL);
                    delete pic[0];
                    imgnum = imgnum + 1;
        }
```

then there is a long section of flips and rotates on the images in newpic, according to various random values.

```
wpimage->DrawImage(newpic[k],(j*nwidth),(((k+1)*whitespace)+htot),nwidth,nh[k]);
wp.Save(L"C:\\Temp\\wallpaper\\nwallpaper.jpg", &jpegClsid, NULL);
delete newpic;
setWall();
delete wpimage;
delete wp;
return 0;
}
```

When I attempt to delete the Image objects, I get an error that says either it can not delete objects that are not pointers, or it cannot convert from GDIplus::Image to void*

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: That is not a great code snippet.  The C++/CLI language intentionally hides the IDisposable interface.  It adopted C++ semantics, you use the *delete* operator instead.  So it is simply `delete newpic[0];`  If you omit the ^ hat, like you did with pic, then the compiler auto-generates it, similar to RAII.

Comment: That gives me undeclared identifier errors, which seems odd, since it is declared.  And yeah I know the code snippet isn't real good, but I didn't think all of the flips and rotates were needed, and the loop is just looped through imgnum.

Comment: Post real code, I can't do anything with this mess.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you have `Image pic(rimg);`
But you are doing `delete pic[0];`
`pic` is not a pointer.. not dynamically allocated or something... nor is a array (or maybe it is.. but intuitively I think no..)

*** Add ***
Oh yeah, if you already solved this, suggests you close the question or at least mention it...